# How to enable Multer(fileUpload) package globally in nestjs?

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, nestjs, multer

I am trying to use Multer Async Configuration, I have used this in my App Module which is the root module

```
MulterModule.registerAsync({
  useClass: MulterConfigService,
});
```

And created a multer-config.service.ts file for multer options

```
 @Injectable()
 export class MulterServiceConfig implements MulterOptionsFactory {
    createMulterOptions() {
        const interceptor = {
            storage: memoryStorage(),
            fileFilter: (req, file, callback) => {
                if (!file.originalname.match(/\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$/)) {
                    return callback(new Error('Only image files are allowed!'), false);
                }
                callback(null, true);
            },
            limits: {
                files: 1,
                fileSize: 640 * 480
            },
        }
        return interceptor;
    }
};
```

Somehow I am not able to import it to my other modules/ or to use it globally.
I tried another way round which is directly importing into my specific module, not in root module and it works fine, but I want to use it globally.

I also tried to create a separate module for multer and allow it with @Global() decorator but its also not showing any difference.

Comment: Could you show us the structure of your modules please ?

Comment: 1- src  -> app Module(imports all other modules components)

  2 - src -> driver component ->module, controller, service etc